# Substract sql value from two different table have different ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables :

table1

| ID | X |
| --- | --- |
| 1111111 | 10000 |
| 2222222 | 20000 |
| 3333333 | 30000 |

table2

| ID | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 4444444 | 1234 |
| 5555555 | 5678 |
| 6666666 | 3456 |

I need substract the X in tables1 with Y in tables2 | something like X = X - Y

I've tried something like this

```
    "INSERT INTO messages (incoming_msg_id, outgoing_msg_id, msg) 
     VALUES ({$incoming_id}, {$outgoing_id}, '{$message}'), 

     SELECT table1.X, table2.Y, (table1.X-table2.Y)
     UPDATE table1
     INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
     SET table1.X = (table1.X-table2.Y)"
```

I want the UPDATE TABLE1 executed when the INSERT INTO triggered

But i did'nt notice whats wrong with the SELECT UPDATE code ?
Any idea?

edit :
full code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
include_once "config.php";
$outgoing_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$incoming_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incoming_id']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);
if(!empty($message)){
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO messages (incoming_msg_id, outgoing_msg_id, msg)
                            VALUES ({$incoming_id}, {$outgoing_id}, '{$message}')") or die();
```

Comment: The rule which allows to define the value from what row of the table 2 must be substracted from definite row of the table 1 must exist. What is this rule? Remember - positional order is not safe for this purposes...

Comment: You can't use `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in the same query. Just do the `UPDATE`.

Comment: If you want this to be triggered when inserting into `messages`, use `CREATE TRIGGER`.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CREATE TRIGGER` to execute the `UPDATE` whenever inserting into `messages.

```
CREATE TRIGGER messages_t1_t2 AFTER INSERT on messages
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE table1 AS t1
    CROSS JOIN table2 AS t2
    SET t1.X = t1.X - t2.Y
    WHERE t1.id = NEW.incoming_msg_id AND t2.id = NEW.outgoing_msg_id;
```

Comment: since the $incoming_id used to search X value in table1 and $outgoing_id to search Y value in table2 and then do X-Y, your JOIN SET, didn't update the table value. And i still trying to figure it out

Comment: Is it supposed to be `t1.id = $incoming_id and t2.id = $outgoing_id` instead of `t1.id = t2.id`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the `NEW` values from the `INSERT` to get the appropriate IDs.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE t1.id = NEW.incoming_msg_id AND t2.id = NEW.outgoing_msg_...' at line 5 it gives me this error

Comment: Sorry, had the clauses out of order. `SET` goes before `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

You should split it into step by steps:

- Update `X = X - Y`
- Insert to `messages`
- Select origin values, I guess the values you need is `X_Old, Y, X_New`. So I changed `SELECT table1.X, table2.Y, (table1.X-table2.Y)` to `SELECT (table1.X + table2.Y), table2.Y, table1.X` because the data was updated.

You can check the full script here:

```
UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
SET table1.X = (table1.X-table2.Y);

INSERT INTO messages (incoming_msg_id, outgoing_msg_id, msg) 
VALUES ({$incoming_id}, {$outgoing_id}, '{$message}');

SELECT (table1.X + table2.Y), table2.Y, table1.X
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID;
```

Comment: Mmm... I forgot to tell that $incoming_id used to search X value in table1 and $outgoing_id to search Y value in table2 and then do X-Y

Comment: @AzisSofyanPrasetyo could you show full of your scripts?

Comment: edited. you can see thee full code

Comment: @AzisSofyanPrasetyo why do you have to search by value in 2 tables instead of ID on 1 table that you already joined? Could you show me where do you want to put the `where` condition which those variables ($incoming_id and $outgoing_id)?

Comment: Ohh. i see. i think there is more efficient way than that. since X and Y is different column